# Install MATLAB Engine for Python

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to install MATLAB Engine for Python to call python functions

I tried the steps on Help
I'm using MATLAB 2015a

I can't run setup.py from CMD

in the Help instructions they asked me to find setup.py on this dir:

```
   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\matlabroot\extern\engines\python

but when I searched on matlab dir I found it on this dir :
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\extern\engines\python
```

I used both of these Codes to install this engine from CMD (as Admin)

```
cd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\extern\engines\python
python setup.py install
```

I tried Python27 and Python34
here is the problem
with 64-bit version CMD returns error when I use "`Python` " on `python setup.py install`
error is:
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command

then I tried setup.py install it returns this error:

```
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

or: setup.py --help-commands

or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

when I tried both of these codes with Python 32-bit it returns:

```
error: 32bit python does not work with 64bit MATLAB. Please check your version of Python
```

Comment: Do you have a 64bit version of python installed?

Comment: Yes I tried with both of versions

Comment: First problem (error: no commands supplied) with 64 bit version

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full path to the 64bit version of `python.exe`?  Like `C:\[path_to_python_dir]\python.exe setup.py install`? (replace `[path_to_python_dir]` with the path to the directory where `python.exe` is found).

Comment: thanks It worked with me ^_^

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the full path to the 64bit version of `python.exe`.  In the commandline:

```
C:\[path_to_python_dir]\python.exe setup.py install
```

Replace `[path_to_python_dir]` with the path to the directory where `python.exe` is found.

Answer (score 1):

To call Python from your operating system prompt, either add the full path to Python to your PATH environment variable, or include the full path when you call the Python interpreter.